# Numerical methods for PDEs: Spectral methods for nonlinear Burgers' equation and choosing between transforming spatial versus frequency domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

I was watching really nice video by [Steve Brunton](https://youtu.be/mMdIxa5qC9Y) on applications of the Fourier Transform to solving partial differential equations. The approach is actually quite interesting for solving the nonlinear Burgers' equation:

$$
u_t + uu_x = \nu u_{xx}
$$

In previous examples, Brunton used the Fourier transform to convert the PDE equation to a system of ODEs in the frequency domain, solve the equations numerically in the frequency domain, and then transform back to the original time domain. However, in the Burgers' equation problem, he showed the Fourier transformation of spatial variable $u(x, t)$, the computation of the derivatives in the spatial domain, and then the inverse transformation of $u_x, u_{xx}$ back to the original domain for computation in some standard ODE scheme like RK.

I can follow the method just fine, but it was not clear what the criteria is for transforming a PDE into the spatial versus frequency domains? How would I choose which domain for the transformation, or do I get the same result independent of my choice of spatial or frequency domain? In this Burgers' equation case, it seems like transforming the spatial variable lets me apply the transform to both the first and second derivatives--instead of a single time derivative. But I was looking for some more general principle if anything like that exists. In other words, do I get different results or accuracy when I Fourier transform this problem to the frequency domain instead  the spatial domain?

Comment: Note the discretization of the spatial domain $\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]$ using a uniform grid with step size $dx = \frac{L}{N}$. This discretization is what you can choose. The discretization in the frequency domain is then completely determined by the definition of the DFT, which is what the FFT computes.

Comment: There is no Boundary condition in the video but an initial condition so it is easier to Fourier Transform in space. Also, for the nonlinear PDE, the FFT in space makes more sense because the resulting ODE in time is of the form $\dot{\hat{u}}=f(\hat{u})$ where $f$ is a nonlinear function because of the $uu_x$ term in the PDE: there are tons of classical ODE solvers for this ODE. Fourier Transforming in time is not ideal here but it could be done when initial conditions are not of interest (ie, for forced periodic solutions for instance).